# can not telnet to a server connection refuse

Tags: iptables, telnet

I have two server with these specifications:

1. IP address: 192.168.1.94
2. IP address: 192.168.1.221

I want to `telnet` to the first one from the second one (to port 5029) but I get this error:

```
root@debian:~# telnet 192.168.1.94 5029
Trying 192.168.1.94...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I can telnet from 192.168.1.94 to itself. this means that a program is listening to 5029 port:

```
[root@myelastix ~]# telnet localhost 5029
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to myelastix.mohaymen.co (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I thought may be firewall is blocking connection in 192.168.1.94 server but these are firewall rules:

```
[root@myelastix ~]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

besides I stopped iptables also but nothing happens again:

```
[root@myelastix ~]# service iptables stop
Flushing firewall rules:                                   [  OK  ]
Setting chains to policy ACCEPT: filter                    [  OK  ]
Unloading iptables modules:                                [  OK  ]
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I just installed telnetd on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04) to try this and I can connect from both the localhost and from my server (after ssh-ing) into it. Please update your question with the distro and distro-version info, and possible which telnet daemon you installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you do this?

```
[root@myelastix ~]# telnet 192.168.1.94 5029
```

If not, make sure `telnetd` is configured to listen on an external interface.

```
netstat -tulpn | grep :5029
```

Comment: can't do `telnet 192.168.1.94 5029` neither and the output of netstat is `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5029              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2848/voipmonitor`

Comment: There you have it. telnetd is configured to only accept connections from localhost.
Check /etc/xinetd.d/telnet file and add
`bind = 192.168.1.94`