# Unable to telnet to a server

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, telnet, connectivity

Here are 2 servers

- 192.168.0.12
- 192.168.0.21

there is a service running in 50070 port in server 192.168.0.12

when I do telnet from 192.168.0.21 server it fails:

```
$telnet 192.168.0.12  50070
Trying 192.168.0.12...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.12: Connection refused
```

When I give hostname then also it fails:

```
$telnet master1.mycluster 50070
Trying 192.168.0.12...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.12: Connection refused
```

Even when I try from 192.168.0.12 it fails if I give the IP address:

```
$telnet 192.168.0.12 50070
Trying 192.168.0.12...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.12: Connection refused
```

But it works if I give the hostname:

```
$telnet master1.mycluster 50070
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to master1.mycluster.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

I found this question [can not telnet to a server connection refuse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167069/can-not-telnet-to-a-server-connection-refuse), but I tried all the possibilities. These are what I tried:

1. Turned off iptables in both the servers
2. Added ALL: ALL in cat /etc/hosts.allow
3. Made sure that the service is running in that port

But none of these work for me.

Here is my /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       master1.mycluster       master1
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4      localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.12 master1.mycluster master1
192.168.0.21 slave1.mycluster slave1
```

Is there anything else that I am missing to make it working ?

Comment: My guess is that /etc/hosts has a 127.0.0.1 entry for “master1.mycluster” — notice what it resolves to.

Comment: What does `telnet 127.0.0.1 50070` do? What addresses is the server configured to listen on. Show config file, or code.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor telnet 127.0.0.1 50070 works when running on the server where the process runs in 50070. I am pretty new to this world so where can I find the addresses that server configured to listen on? I spinned up these 2 machines using vagrant.

Comment: @JeffSchaller this is how /etc/hosts looks like
127.0.0.1       master1.mycluster       master1

127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.12 master1.mycluster master1
192.168.0.21 slave1.mycluster slave1

Comment: @JeffSchaller I will add it in question as its not getting intended properly

Comment: You are sure the service is running on the public address (192) and not just the local one (127)?

Comment: Too know how to configure a server, we would need to know what the server is. But that is another question. So accept @rusty's answer. As it is correct, and ask another but you will need a lot more detail about what you are doing. (Try the manual first). Then tell us what you have tried and what went wrong (in a new question).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I accepted his answer as it really explains what is going on. But could give me a brief idea what I need to do to overcome this ? So that at least I know how to google it and checking at the right manual.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Exactly I think that is what I am doing wrong, at least from what others are saying here. Can you redirect me to some question or something so that I understand how to run service in public address instead of local one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service is listening on the loopback address only, `127.0.0.1`.

When you make a connection from `192.168.0.21` or when you specify the `ip` address it does not work, as your service is not listening on that `ip`.

When you use the `hostname` from `192.168.0.12` it works because it is connecting to the loopback address. This is because it will look in your hosts file first, `/etc/hosts`, which has an entry pointing that `hostname` to your loopback `ip`: `127.0.0.1       master1.mycluster`

Comment: shackle ford. Thank you, this explains what is going on. If I need to make it listen on connection from other servers then what I need to do? I know this question needs lot of details, but if you can give me an idea then I at least try to find how to do it from google. Mine is cantos 7 VMS.

Comment: This will depend on the service, a lot of applications will only listen on `loopback` by default. There will normally be an option to tell it which address to listen on, and normally setting it to 0.0.0.0 means listen on all addresses. But this will depend on the the application.